# Flutter. Add a json.decode value to a String that can be used in the UI

Tags: json, asynchronous, flutter

Maybe this is a simple question, but I can't find the answer to it.
My app has 2 screens. 1st has a single button

```
onPressed: () {
      fetchCurrentTitle();
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2Widget()));
    },
```

fetchCurrentTitle() method fetches data from json and decodes it.
I can see the return using:

```
final streamFullTitle = json.decode(response.body)['data'][0]['title'];
print(streamFullTitle);
```

I get the desired response of the current title in the console.

In the 2nd screen I have a hardcoded List. Where items have these values:

```
class List {
  String id;
  String streamer;
  String logoUrl;
  String title;
}
```

The first three attribute in List class dont need to change so they are hardcoded. I just need to assign the title value from`fetchCurrentTitle()` to the `String title.` in class List.
[Look of one of my list items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12pUZ.png)

My fetchCurrentTitle() works as intended

```
Future<String> fetchCurrentTitle() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(...
```

I want the user to push the button on the first screen to go to the second screen and show a spinner with title "looking for title" and then get the new title instead of waiting fetchCurrentTitle() to complete only entering the second screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Your title and what you comment at the bottom of the post are not matching. Check the question guidelines to make improvements: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah I see the confusion. As a newbie I am stuck in this way I am trying to get the result. Now I think there is a better way to do this. At this point my json request returns info about a specific user. I need to form the request in a way that I get a bunch of users in the selected category. Then iterate trough them and create a list and a ListView with tiles and FutureBuilder. I can find video tutorials on this way so it seems the most correct. You saw what the end goal should be - list of items with updated data. I gonna try this approach tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your `fetchCurrentTitle()` in the second screen on

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  fetchCurrentTitle()
  /// show or set visibility for loading spinner
}
```

After you get the title value, you can simply assign new title by

```
List existingList = new List(id,streamer,logoUrl,title);
existingList.id = titleValueFromApi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sample_project_for_api/Employee.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('home page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
            },
            child: const Text('First Page')),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  Employee sampleData;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getYouData();
  }

  Future<String> loadPersonFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  getYouData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String jsonString = await loadPersonFromAssets();
    final data = employeeFromJson(jsonString);
    sampleData = data;

    // this is where you get the data from the network

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      // this is sample delay for you to know the delay.
      // you can say this is loading your data

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(

        child: _isLoading
                //here give your message getting the title
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('your 1st hardcoded text'),
                        Text('your 2st hardcoded text'),
                        Text('your 3st hardcoded text'),
                        Text(
                            'This is your dynamic data after fetching :${sampleData.employeeName}')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

check out this example you will give you an idea of what to do

1) going from one page to another page

2) loading you data , while that showing the spinner

3) on fetching the data update the UI.

let me know about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import 'dart:convert';

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 1")),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Goto Page2"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Page2(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  Future<void> _initLoader;
  String _title;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initLoader = _loadInitData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _loadInitData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    //_title = await fetchCurrentTitle();
    _title = "This is the Loaded Title";
  }

  Future<String> fetchCurrentTitle() async {
    Response response = await get("...");
    return json.decode(response.body)['data'][0]['title'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 2")),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initLoader,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Text("Looking for Title"),
                ],
              ),
            );
          else if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(
              child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
            );
          else
            return Center(
              child: Text("$_title"),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```